# Is Self-Modifying Turing Machine equivalent to NTM or TM?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, np-complete, neural-networks, fuzzy-logic

Let SMTM be Turing Machine, but the commands recorded in which can change to others in some random way (for example, choose with a 50/50 probability the command to move to the right or move to the left), and SM-NTM be non-deterministic Turing Machine with same property (note that NTM non-deterministic in sense of choosing next action, but not the rule, which describes this actions). A difference between a self-modifying Turing machine and TM/NTM: instead of one command for any given situation, or a set of commands in a non-deterministic Turing machine, there is a fuzzy set of commands.

In addition to the question from the title: Is there any papers which describes these sort of theoretical models of computation? In particular, I am interested in the applicability of Rice's theorem for a given computational model. Maybe, there is some connection to quantum computers, NP-hardness, etc.?

The problem that prompted me to this question:

There are neural networks that have an element of non-determinism, where at a certain stage the numbers change by adding random numbers (obtained, for example, from weather observations or observation of the decay of unstable atoms, that is, really random numbers) - do such models have restrictions superimposed on a Turing machine?

Comment: You are looking for [probabilistic Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_Turing_machine), which are neither deterministic nor non-deterministic. It's a third kind of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Randomness is not the same as non-determinism -- at least, not the non-determinism that is referred to when people talk about non-deterministic Turing machines.

See [Can an algorithm be truly non-deterministic?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/92203/755), [Differences and relationships between randomized and nondeterministic algorithms?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/5008/755), https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/632/5038, [Are nondeterministic algorithm and randomized algorithms algorithms on a deterministic Turing machine?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/32536/755).

There is plenty of study of randomized algorithms and the power of randomness.  You can read about BPP, the open question whether BPP = P, etc.

There is plenty of study of non-deterministic algorithms and the power of non-determinism, too.  For instance, you can read about the open question whether P = NP.

One common hypothesis/guess/speculation right now is that probably randomness doesn't add much power (maybe P = BPP) but non-determinism is very powerful (probably P != NP).